# Unable to see the saved image as it looks in imageview

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image

I use following code to save image that is taken by camera

```
File storageDir= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myphoto.png");//  getAlbumName()
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(storageDir);
ObjectOutputStream oos =new ObjectOutputStream(out);

mImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100 , oos);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

I get "myphoto.png" in "\pictures" folder, however when try to open the image I can see just black window instead of the image. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: This is not html. It will be easier for people who can help you if you specify the right technologies.

Comment: did you tried  imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not compress into `ObjectOutputStream oos` but into `FileOutputStream out`. `ObjectOutputStream` is for Java objects and it adds unwanted data to your output.

```
File storageDir= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myphoto.png");//  getAlbumName()
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(storageDir);

mImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```